# Closing a menu only with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I succeeded to remove javascript in my mobile design and open side menu only by CSS. My side menu is like:

```
<div class="all-content">
    <div id="menu-content" class="menu-content">
        .... menu content....
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to open menu:

```
 <a href="#menu-content"><i class="fa fa-navigation></i></a>
```

and in CSS:

```
.menu-content{
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    left: -100%;
}

.menu-content:target{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And **this works fine**!

What I want is to close this menu by clicking "anywhere out of the menu" without javascript.

I'm aware that clicking **any link** will close this menu but I couldn't find how to do it binding with whole content.

Thanks by now.

Comment: Let me know if the answer didnt help or you meant something else

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a checkbox and have it essentially hidden with `opacity:0`
2. Have it cover large areas with `width/height:500px`
3. Have it `position:absolute` to not effect the position of surrounding elements
4. Write a css style to hide the siblings of the `:checked` checkbox

```css
#CheckBox:checked ~ .menu-content {
  display: none;
}
#CheckBox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<input id="CheckBox" type="checkbox" />
<div id="menu-content" class="menu-content">
  Side Menu
</div>
```